How to correctly transfer Children to the Angular Directive
I'm trying to pass all FormGroups that are in childrens to my directive. Why are they not transmitted?
I tried using ViewChildren and ContentChildren but the result is undefined
<div block="tab" [class.is-active]="toggleGroup.value === 'output'" fieldGroupValidation>
        <app-rubric-theme-date></app-rubric-theme-date>
        <app-authors></app-authors>
    </div>

@Directive({
    selector: '[fieldGroupValidation]'
})
export class FieldGroupValidationDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @ViewChildren(FormGroup) controls: QueryList<FormGroup>;
    constructor(
        
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // console.log('contorls', this.controls);
        // console.log('controls names: ', this.controls);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('contorls', this.controls);
    }


There are form groups inside the components in the template

Try Component with <ng-content></ng-content> as template and [fieldGroupValidation]  as selector. ContentChildren should work in that case, I think

Look, there is a problem there, in your @ViewChild you are specifying that you would like to have all the forms in your other components, (i presume that)
<div block="tab" [class.is-active]="toggleGroup.value === 'output'" 
fieldGroupValidation>
    <app-rubric-theme-date></app-rubric-theme-date>
    <app-authors></app-authors>
</div>

Like, in your directive, you expect that inside the directive scope, you recieve a FormGroup, or all the others FormGroups, but that does not works that way.
FormGroup is not a class that you can reference in your ViewChild/ViewChildren/ContenChildren/ContentChild, because it is a utilitarian class used by angular, you can only reference DOM elements.
https://angular.dev/api/forms/FormGroup
You need to specify the thing that you want from your component, like this:
<div block="tab" [class.is-active]="toggleGroup.value === 'output'" 
fieldGroupValidation>
    <app-rubric-theme-date></app-rubric-theme-date>
    <app-authors #authors></app-authors>
</div>

now in your typescript could be something like this:
@Directive({
selector: '[fieldGroupValidation]'
})
export class FieldGroupValidationDirective implements 
   OnInit, 
   OnDestroy, 
   AfterViewInit //Do not forget to implement the interface
{
@ViewChild("authors") authorsComponent!: YourAuthorComponentClass;
//You could also do this:
@ViewChild(RubicThemeComponent) myRubicThemeComponent!: RubicThemeComponent;
constructor(
    
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    // console.log('contorls', this.controls);
    // console.log('controls names: ', this.controls);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.authorsComponent);
}

So now, you have access to all other attributes in your authors component, you could then specify your controls like this:
this.authorsComponent.myFormsControls

now you could do your other operations with your form.
